# Delete files with less than x characters in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script which is given a directory as a parameter and removes all files with less than 4 characters. My script is currently as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $1
rm ???
rm ??
rm ?
```

This method works but it throws an error whenever a file without <4 characters is present. For example, if there was no 2 character filename in the given directory, an error would be presented where "rm cannot remove any character '??'". I was wondering how I make my bash script so that there is no error like that thrown without using loops or conditionals.

Comment: so just `rm -f` ?

Comment: `rm -f ? ?? ???` would silence it but it looks very dangerous. If you forget to supply any arguments to that script it'll `cd` to your home directory and do the removal there.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeh that worked, thanks. I completely missed that when originally looking over options for the rm command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `rm -f`. From `man rm`:

```
-f, --force  
       ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

To protect against files named literally `--` or `-f`, use a leading `--`.

```
rm -f -- ? ?? ???
```

But that `-f` - it *looks* dangerous (as if `rm` in a script is not dangorous enough). Really a better option is not to use globbing and use `find`:

```
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f '(' -name '?' -o -name '??' -o -name '???' ')' -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable the `nullglob` option so globs that don't match any files are removed.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

cd "$1"
rm ? ?? ???
```

Note that you will now get an error if there are no matching files at all:

```
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the stderr to /dev/null:

```
rm ??? 2>/dev/null
rm ?? 2>/dev/null
rm ? 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

"removes all files with less than 4 characters" and "without using loops or conditionals" you can use:

- find all files with the length of the filename between 1 and 4 chars:
  `find . -type f -exec basename '{}' ';' | egrep '^.{1,3}$'` where you can replace `.` with the desired directory as argument.
- And afterwards you can `rm -f $(find . -type f -exec basename '{}' ';' | egrep '^.{1,3}$)'`